# Only refresh parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I am using a modal to show the shopping cart. Users can delete items in the modal. So what I want to do is that after they delete an item, the parent page will be refreshed and the modal should still show up.
Right now, After I click on the "delete button" in the modal, the parent page will be refreshed but the modal CLOSES UP.

**My code:**

```
$(function(){
  $('.delete').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url:'/polls/cart__Delete/'+$(this).attr('data-id'),
        success: function(data){
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
            parent.location.reload(true);
        },  
     });

   });
});
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to refresh the parent page, since your making a asynchronous request, cant you just update the respective block on your parent page instead of refreshing, else there is no point in making ajax request

Comment: Why refresh the page after the delete, is this not the reason why you are using ajax in the first place? Why dont you just remove the part of the DOM that contains the item to be deleted?

Comment: Because after deleting an item, I have to refresh the parent page where shows item quantities for cart. For example, before deleting items, the parent page shows cart(8)--8 reflects item quantities in the shopping cart. After deleting, it should show cart(7) or something. But now, I have to refresh the parent page by hand to update item quantities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('.delete').click(function(e){
     $.ajax({
        url:'/polls/cart__Delete/'+$(this).attr('data-id'),
        success: function(data){
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
            parent.location.reload(true);
        },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('Loading failed!!');       }  
     });
    e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: a very weird thing  happned...Now when I delete items from modal, the modal will lose up and the parent page will be refreshed.. I don't think I have changed any codes.